# Reading special characters from the file using java?

Tags: java, file, encoding, character-encoding

I am using java to read a text file and which has some special chars like `Yen(¥)`. I have not specified any encoding/charset while reading a file and is working fine in windows. But if i deploy the same in unix machine then `¥` is replaced by '`?`'. Now i am going to specify charset windows-1252 to avoid the issue. will `windows-1252` work on `unix/linux` boxes? My unix box charset is set to '`utf-8`'. am using below the code:

```
LineIterator iterator =FileUtils.lineIterator(*filename*,"Windows-1252");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912313/reading-special-characters-from-file-java

Answer (score 2):

The class `StandardCharsets` gives you a list of encodings / charsets that are "guaranteed to be available on every implementation of the Java platform."

This list doesn't contain the Windows encodings but for most common Java versions on Windows, Mac and Linux, `Cp1251` is available.

Note that you'll get a `UnsupportedCharsetException` or `UnsupportedEncodingException` when it's not available, so the code above is safe (in the sense that it won't produce garbage).

If you want to be really safe, the common approach is to use only UTF-8 encoded data in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, I usualy solve this by saving the text file in UTF-8 encoding with your text editor, and then specifying UTF-8 again when opening that file from your java program.